# kafka-cluster-zookeper networking issues in newer versions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, strimzi

zookeeper logs indicate a networking issue where the zookeeper service is unable to resolve the address for kafka-cluster-zookeeper-0.kafka-cluster-zookeeper-nodes.test.svc on port 2888.

> zookeeper logs:  ERROR Couldn't bind to
> kafka-cluster-zookeeper-0.kafka-cluster-zookeeper-nodes.test.svc/:2888
> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Leader)

The workaround is to restart the pod once or twice to start without any errors. Also, this happens less frequently probably because of slow dns and looks like this is happening frequently with newer versions of zookeeper.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Strimzi operator version: 0.38.0
Reproduced environments: KIND, K3s, EKS

Comment: Is there option to get rid of Zookeeper and just go with Kraft based deployment?

Comment: Agreed. Zookeeper will be completely removed from Kafka 4.0 release. Otherwise, you need to share your Strimzi config files and CoreDNS within a namespace should not be "slow", and Zookeeper version has nothing to do with DNS resolution

Comment: Actually, the ZooKeeper version does make a difference. Some of the ZooKeeper versions used in newer Kafka versions do not handle unresolved hosts well and get stuck. So on some clusters (we never found any common factor causing this), where older ZooKeeper versions worked fine, new versions have problems.

Comment: I think should just have to wait till Kafka 4.0 release to get rid of zookeeper. In the meanwhile, Is there any way to make zookeeper wait till the address is resolved. I dont think CRDs of cluster will allow any such implementation.